# Vim regex backreference

Tags: regex, vim

I want to do this:

```
%s/shop_(*)/shop_\1 wp_\1/
```

Why doesn't `shop_(*)` match anything?

Comment: I'm a little closer: `%s/shop_/& wp_\1`

Comment: If I didn't understand correctly, try adding examples.

Comment: This question would be more useful to future SO users if an example was added of what is being attempted with the regex.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want `%s/shop_\(.*\)/shop_\1 wp_\1/`

Escape the capturing parenthesis and use `.*` to match any number of any character.

(Your search is searching for "shop_" followed by any number of opening parentheses followed by a closing parenthesis)

Answer (score 81):

There's several issues here.

1. parens in vim regexen are not for capturing -- you need to use `\( \)` for captures.
2. `*` doesn't mean what you think. It means "0 or more of the previous", so your regex means "a string that contains `shop_` followed by 0+ `(` and then a literal `)`. 
   You're looking for `.`, which in regex means "any character". Put together with a star as `.*` it means "0 or more of any character". You probably want at least one character, so use `.\+` (`+` means "1 or more of the previous")

Use this: `%s/shop_\(.\+\)/shop_\1 wp_\1/`.

Optionally end it with `g` after the final slash to replace for all instances on one line rather than just the first.

Comment: Just a nit: the existing regex didn't search for a literal `*)`, just a literal `)`.

Comment: So basically Vim wants reverse escaping: escape all regex syntax (e.g. `\(re\)\?move` to match both 'move' and 'remove') *instead of* escaping anything that should be taken literally.

Answer (score 3):

If you would like to avoid having to escape the capture parentheses and make the regex pattern syntax closer to other implementations (e.g. PCRE), add `\v` (very magic!) at the start of your pattern (see [`:help \magic`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#/magic) for more info):

```
:%s/\vshop_(*)/shop_\1 wp_\1/
```

Answer (score 0):

@Luc if you look here: [regex-info](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html), you'll see that vim is behaving correctly.   Here's a parallel from sed:

```
echo "123abc456" | sed 's#^([0-9]*)([abc]*)([456]*)#\3\2\1#'
sed: -e expression #1, char 35: invalid reference \3 on 's' command's RHS
```

whereas with the "escaped" parentheses, it works:

```
echo "123abc456" | sed 's#^\([0-9]*\)\([abc]*\)\([456]*\)#\3\2\1#'
456abc123
```

I hate to see vim maligned - especially when it's behaving correctly.

PS I tried to add this as  a comment, but just couldn't get the formatting right.