# vim search and replace with the effect of reformatting some middle characters

Tags: search, vim, replace, save, character

So, so I have this in some file:

```
ABCxxx.yyyDEF
```

and I want to change it to be:

```
HELLOxxx.yyyWORLD
```

Is there a way to do this? / How?

I was playing with using wildcards, e.g.

```
:%s/ABC.*DEF/HELLO.*WORLD/g
```

but, .* in the replaced HELLO_WORLD doesnt save the replaced .* characters. It just comes out as HELLO.*WORLD

Help appreaciated,

Pachun

Answer (score 3, accepted):

s/ABC\(xxx.yyy\)WORD/JJJ\1MOO/

Whatever is in \(\) will be remembered and can be used in the replacement string.

see:
[vim regex backreference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3339080/vim-regex-backreference)